# Winforms: How to draw line over control without invalidating it

Tags: c#, winforms, paint, invalidation

i have a class that draws waveforms of audio. I'm drawing it in OnPaint function. Now i need to draw a line that shows where on the waveform we are at current moment. I can calculate the position but when i try to draw it i need to call Invalidate() and that forces form to redraw all that waveform chart data (a lot of points).

So is there a way to put some transparent element over this one and then call Invalidate() only on that element? i was trying with picture box but no sucess...

```
//main form    
private void timer100ms_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                customWaveViewer1.currentPosition = (int)((stream.Position / (float)stream.Length) * customWaveViewer1.Width);
                customWaveViewer1.overlayLabel.Invalidate(false);
            }

   //drawing function in my class
   private void overlayLabelInvalidate(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, currentPosition, 0, currentPosition, this.Height);
        }

  //constructor
  public CustomWaveViewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            this.PenColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
            this.PenWidth = 1;

            overlayLabel = new PictureBox();
            overlayLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height);
            overlayLabel.Location = new Point(this.Left, this.Top);
            overlayLabel.Visible = true;
            overlayLabel.BackColor=Color.FromArgb(0,0,0,0);
            overlayLabel.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.overlayLabelInvalidate);
            Controls.Add(overlayLabel);
        }
```

Comment: Yes you can do just that but you need to make sure that the overlying control is sitting __inside__ the bottom control: `overlayControl.Parent = bottomControl:` Can you explain what is what in your code? CustomWaveViewer: is that the form or a class or what?

Comment: Also: If the redrawing of the waves is expensive do consider drawing into a Bitmap!

Comment: Ok i will try draw in Bitmap.

Comment: If you are already creating the overlayLabel as a child of a CustomWaveViewer class set its Location to point(0,0)!

Comment: You can prepare the next Bitmap in advance in a different thread.. but the original idea should work, too.

Comment: I guess I should revoke my first comment: Your overlay is transparent and therefore it will call for its Parent to draw the background. Therefore the expensive drawing will always happen. Bitmap is the most efficient way to go.

Comment: no it is not per se. Activate double buffering and use the rectangle in painteventargs will do the trick just fine. You only need to repaint a very small portion of your waveform. If the points are stored based on some basis of time, you should be able to get those points quickly and avoid too much painting.

Comment: This make assumptions about the drawing code that are not called for.

Comment: Drawing code is supposed to be efficient. Change it if it is not. The combination of double buffering and efficient painting logic will give a more responsive GUI. There is a waveform and there is a timeline. That points are stored on some basis of time is hardly an assumption. Storing them in a list sorted on time, and moving quickly to the applicable time, and breaking the iteration when you are out the time interval can be already enough in this case. In sw there is no such thing as a single best solution. This is a good solution, your bitmap soluton might be a good one too. The op decides.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are saying is not exactly true.
In the painteventargs there is a rectangle indicating the small portion of the window that needs to be repainted.
Also when you invalidate, you don't necessarily need to invalidate the whole form.
In your case you might want to invalidate only the old and new position of the marker that indicates where you are in the waveform.
So in your algorithm of your paint method, it is really up to you to make it efficient and only paint that part of the window that really needs repainting and to skip the part that does not need repainting.
It really can make a huge difference.

To make it even more look professional, set double buffering on.
No need to hastle with bitmaps of the whole image you have yourself, that is just what double buffering is all about, and forms can do it for you.

I copied following excerpt from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145137(v=vs.85).aspx

BeginPaint fills a PAINTSTRUCT structure with information such as the dimensions of the portion of the window to be updated and a flag indicating whether the window background has been drawn. The application can use this information to optimize drawing. For example, it can use the dimensions of the update region, specified by the rcPaint member, to limit drawing to only those portions of the window that need updating. **If an application has very simple output, it can ignore the update region and draw in the entire window, relying on the system to discard (clip) any unneeded output.** Because the system clips drawing that extends outside the clipping region, only drawing that is in the update region is visible.

In this case there is no simple output and taking this into account is adviced.
I am not saying that creating a bitmap will not work. I am saying that optimizing your drawing logic will solve it just as well.

The information above still stands as windows forms is built on top of the old win32 api.

Comment: Beg to differ. The Parent will usually redraw everything at least in memory, even when with an optimize invalidate not all pixels get sent out. In the case at hand I guess that the drawing is the expensive part and not the dumping of the memory bitmap to the graphics device. And drawing into a Bitmap is not any more difficult or more hassle than drawing onto the surface. As for doublebuffering: It is on in his code already

Comment: Think about how the `Paint` event could __possibly__ restrict itself to only those `Drawxxx` calls the change the invalidated area?! Therefore it must go through __completely__. And if that means a hundred thousand calls they will all have to be completed. - Afterwards a small portion may all that's necessary to update the screen, but then its too late..!

Comment: And messing with the draw code yourself is most certainly more hassle than drawing into a bitmap. Plus you get the added bonus of actually making use of multiple cores, if needed..

Comment: I have actually implemented some complex forms like this and I can tell you it is a world of difference. I have even gone as far as to call scrollwindowex which is not available in windows forms. The problem of only painting that portion that is invalidated in a window is a well known problem. The way I describe it is best practice. It's all in the algorithm you employ. I have efficient ways of getting the objects that need repainting that intersect with the small part of the window that needs repainting.

Comment: Win api has scrollwindow and ways to copy part of a window for a reason, to avoid complex paint logic altogether.